# Response cut while reading System.Net.Sockets

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have this code inside of a controller that is called from a view by multiple users. The purpose is to read data from a socket while the socket has information to deliver. Multiple calls can happen simultaneously. The problem is, for a same call the Socket will sometimes cut the message. We will not read it entirely. Is there something wrong in my call that could lead to an incomplete reading of the Socket ? I am not able to reproduce it on my dev environment I just know that on the production we have responses from the Socket being randomly cut / incomplete.

```
int byteCount = 1;
string response = "";
int total = 0;
bytesReceived = new Byte[8000];
bool bytesAreAvailable = true;
while (byteCount > 0 || bytesAreAvailable)
{
   try {
         byteCount = m_oSocket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
         total += byteCount;
         Debug.WriteLine("Bytecount: " + byteCount.ToString());
         Debug.WriteLine("Avalable: " + m_oSocket.Available.ToString());
         if (m_oSocket.Available > 0)
             bytesAreAvailable = true;
          else
             bytesAreAvailable = false; //Everything was read
         response += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, byteCount);
       }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
     Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
   }
}
Debug.WriteLine(response.ToString());
```

Thanks a lot for any help / tips you could have on solving my issue

Comment: You're checking whether any more bytes are available *right now*. Just because there aren't any right now doesn't mean that there won't be a millisecond later. If you want to put multiple messages into a stream protocol, you probably want something like length prefix or data to say "I'm done".

Comment: The socket is supposed to answer the call with on message we just don't know its length, that's why I check what is still available.
I don't control the socket or what it is sending I am just connecting to it.

Comment: So is the socket closed at the end of the response? If not, how would you expect to tell the difference between "end of message" and "there's more data coming in a moment"? (It doesn't help that we don't know what kind of socket this is, or what options you've used, mind you...)

Comment: I'll need to ask for confirmation but the message ends when I receive an EOF until then the message is not completely received.

Comment: Right. I would suggest removing all the code that uses `Available` here. Just loop until `Receive` returns 0 - assuming this is a connection-oriented socket and you haven't opted to use a non-blocking mode.

Comment: Also note that if you've got a single socket and multiple threads (you've mentioned a controller "that is called from a view by multiple users") that could well cause problems.